# video doesn't load in firefox using videojs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, video.js

I have this code (changed demo.html of video.js , adding my own source), but the video doesn't load in firefox.
I see in inspector newtork this message: "**El "Content-Type" HTTP de "video/x-f4v" no es compatible. Ha fallado la carga del recurso de medios**"

...

"**Ha fallado la carga de todos los recursos candidatos. Carga de medios pausada.**"

```
  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"
      poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
      data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://xxx.xxxxx.com/svn/loader.php?v=VID_N2xVczxccxzxczxcxzc6756hnbnbn==" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="http://xxx.xxxxx.com/svn/loader.php?v=VID_N2xVczxccxzxczxcxzc6756hnbnbn==" type='video/webm' />
    <source src="http://xxx.xxxxx.com/svn/loader.php?v=VID_N2xVczxccxzxczxcxzc6756hnbnbn==" type='video/ogg' />
      <track kind="captions" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
    <track kind="subtitles" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
  </video>
```

---

I see video properly in chrome and ie9+

**EDIT**
It's strange...if I quit three source tags above, and I add:

```
<source src="http://xxx.xxxxx.com/svn/loader.php?v=VID_N2xVczxccxzxczxcxzc6756hnbnbn==" type='video/flv' />
```

then I see the video properly

Anybody does know how solve it?

Comment: Have you tried it with the demo video loading from the demo server and also the demo video from your own server?

Comment: Not, I tried only with demo in my server, but not in their server....how could I try it in their server?

Comment: So you tried their demo video from your server? If the videos load from their servers (`http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4`), that means, your HTML and plugin initialization is correct and your problem lies on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Content types in .htaccess file on the server like this

- AddType video/mp4 mp4 m4v
- AddType audio/mp4 m4a
- AddType video/ogg ogv
- AddType audio/ogg ogg oga
- AddType video/webm webm

This specifies video format for browsers.

Or maybe the video you are trying to get is only available in `FLV` format.